# tsql to find out sql server alias

Tags: sql-server-2012

Using TSQL, is there any way to find out SQL server alias configured at configuration manager? Such as follows?[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That's a server-level setting, not an instance one - you may be able to use xp_regread but I would strongly consider not getting this information from T-SQL, but from C#/Powershell/etc.

Comment: you can't do it via TSQL. you need to use xp_instance_regread to find the value from the registry. Check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/01/07/connection-alias.aspx, or this: http://sqlservermct.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/create-sql-server-aliases-using-registry-editor/

Comment: I'm with Aaron on this one. Do this discovery outside of T-SQL.